# I-485 date of marriage

Tags: immigration, marriage, greencard

My wife and I are applying for adjustment of status (form I-485) through work authorization (from I-140 - NIW). I'm the NIW applicant and my wife is my the derivative applicant in the I-485.

We got married in March 2017 but did not obtain any government issued certificates since it was an Islamic marriage. We just got our marriage license from the county clerk last week (Jan 2018). Now, I don't know which marriage date should I enter in the I-485 forms? The new one? or the old one?

I am attaching both the old Islamic marriage contract and the new marriage license with my package. Is it bad that the official marriage data is only one week before submitting the application?

Comment: I am not sure if you are using the correct terminology, but getting a "marriage license" doesn't mean you are married. A marriage license is simply a "license" to permit you to get married within a given time period. The marriage must actually be conducted during that time, officiated by someone that has the competence to officiate marriages in your state, and witnessed by someone. Then the official that conducted your marriage would usually report the marriage to the county clerk, who would officially record the marriage and then you can get a "marriage certificate".

Comment: The getting of the "marriage license" and the marriage could happen on the same day (e.g. if you get married at a courthouse or city hall, and it can be officiated by someone from the court or city hall) or it could happen separately (e.g. if you get married in a private ceremony somewhere else). But did someone actually officially "marry" the two of you after you got the license? Or did you just get a "Iicense" and do nothing afterwards?

Comment: Any religious ceremony you may have done outside the marriage laws of the place where it occurred does not count as a legal marriage, so the Islamic marriage you had which you did not get a marriage license for beforehand, is definitely not the date of marriage. I am just trying to see whether you actually got married the second time or not.

Comment: @user102008 I'm sorry. Yes, someone actually married us. We got the license, had it signed in a religious organization and filed at the clerk county office.

I live in Texas, and I think there is no marriage certificate here. The "signed and filed" marriage license seems to be the only marriage record here.

Comment: @user102008 oh, so it doesn't count without a government-issued document. Do you think it is going to be trouble that we're filing the I-485 one week after marriage date?

Comment: You can file as soon after the marriage as you want, as long as you have gotten a certified marriage certificate or equivalent document from your jurisdiction, and you have all the other materials ready. Also note that you can file I-485 first and she can file later if you guys want.